# Modify WooCommerce Edit Coupon fields from functions.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add a new field under "Allowed emails". This field will be called "Restricted emails". I don't want to modify WooCommerce by editing the file `plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-coupon-data.php`. Instead I want to add the new form field through functions.php by using `add_action`. Is this possible?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGcVZ.png)

I've only been able to add the new form field by editing the file:
`plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-coupon-data.php`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MksgG.png)

But again, I don't want to modify plugin due to the obvious reason that my changes will be overwritten when I update the WooCommerce plugin in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `woocommerce_coupon_options_usage_restriction` hook.

This won't put it in the same same `options_group` wrapper but I believe it is as close as you can get.

For example:

```
function add_coupons_restricted_emails_field(){
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id'                => 'restricted_customer_emails',
            'label'             => __( 'Restricted emails', 'woocommerce' ),
            'placeholder'       => __( 'No restrictions', 'woocommerce' ),
            'desc_tip'          => true,
            'type'              => 'email',
            'custom_attributes' => array(
                'multiple' => 'multiple',
            ),
        )
    );
}
add_action("woocommerce_coupon_options_usage_restriction", "add_coupons_restricted_emails_field");
```

Also the coupon ID and the coupon object are passed to the hook if you need them:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_coupon_options_usage_restriction', $coupon->get_id(), $coupon ); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I needed!